# Recurring local notifications using NSTimer don't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, nstimer

The user can select between a couple of minute intervals in a slider (3, 5, 8, 10 etc.).

Since, it is not possible to set a recurring local notifications on custom time (only once in a sec, minute, hour, day...).

I have created a timer that creates a new local notification at the chosen time. The weird thing here is that it works on a physical iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 simulator. But not on a physical iPhone 5, all running iOS 9.3.2.

Below is the code that starts the timer, number is an integer value fetched from the slider (3, 5, 8...):

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(number*60), target: self, selector: Selector("sendNotification"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    print("notification interval set to \(number)")
}

func sendNotification() {
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(number))
    localNotification.alertBody = "This is a test body."
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

It seem to be some kind of hardware difference between iPhone 5 and 6 that affects this solution. What is it and what can I do to make it work on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the issue.

The problem was that NSTimer is not executed if the app gets suspended. It worked in the simulator since apps never seem to suspend there. And it probably worked on the physical iPhone 6 since it has enough memory to not suspend the app quickly.

So, now if the user selects 5min then I create totally 12 notifications with fire dates each staggered by 5min. Each notification then has a repeat interval set to .NSHourCalendarUnit.

This way it's possible to create recurring local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need create `UILocalNotification` and schedule it for all time intervals. And set `fireDate`

```
notification.fireDate(YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL)
UIApplication.sharedApplication.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

something like for your case with NSTimer

```
func sendNotificationNew() -> Void {
   let dateTime = NSDate()
   var notification = UILocalNotification()
   notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
   notification.fireDate(dateTime)
   notification.alertBody("Test")
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

or change your code

```
@IBAction func saveSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dateTime = NSDate().dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow(Double(number*60))
   var notification = UILocalNotification()
   notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
   notification.fireDate(dateTime)
   notification.alertBody("Test")
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code snippets but they don't compile. I added my code for send a notification above and it seem to be similar to yours?

Comment: @Ramon you declare your local notification as a constant, you need change `let localNotification` to `var localNotification`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Changed the declaration to var instead of let. But unfortunately the solution still don't work on a physical iPhone 5 :-/